# how to make 3 conditions in ajax to check user id?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> I try make 3 condition in ajax, to check when creating a new user id.
>   it's already work if 2 condition for (username can be used and username is already in use) but i got problem while user make field is empty in username field, and will display username can be used.
>   i try make `if(data == "")` but it's not working, anybody can help me please? sorry i beginners javascript, still studying

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').change(function(e){
        $('#pesan').html("<img src='loading.gif' />checking...");
        var username = $('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"chk2.php",
            data:"username="+username,
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "")
                {
                    $('#pesan').html("<img src='failed.png' /><span style='color:green;margin-left:10px;'>Cant Empty !!!!</span>");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data == 0){
                        $('#pesan').html("<img src='accept.png' /><span style='color:green;margin-left:10px;'>username can be used</span>");
                    } else {
                        $('#pesan').html("<img src='failed.png' /><span style='color:red;margin-left:10px;'>username is already in use</span>");
                    }
                }   
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="20" name="username" id="username"/></td>
            <td><span id="pesan"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="password" size="20" name="password" id="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></td>
    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

for chk2.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("ptmjp");

$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql = mysql_query("select code_item from stock where code_item='$username'");
$find = mysql_num_rows($sql);

echo $find;
?>
```

Comment: Do you e=mean `if (a) { ... } else if(b) { ... ) else { ... }` ?

Comment: thx for comment, yes its 3 condition 1. empty 2.can used 3.already used, but it's using ajax and only got 1(already) or 0(can used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer, sorry if you complicate
it's just make condition in chk2.php

```
if($username == "")
{
    $find = 2;
    echo $find;
}
else
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select code_item from stock where code_item='$username'");
    $find = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo $find;
}
```

so just chnage javascript if 1 = already, 0 can ,2 empty 
Thx for ur comment

Answer (score 2):

i think data = '' and data = 0 both work same . 0 also prefer as null so change 0  to other

Comment: so it's cant ?, i already try null or "" it's still not working

Comment: so try data === 0 instead of data == 0 . i hope this will solve your problem. === match with exact match (data type)